# Android app always stops unexpectedly, trying to do event handler?

Tags: java, android, events, handler

So every time I run this code my Android app stops unexpectdly, and i dont get why...

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class TheStupidTest extends Activity {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    text1.setText("well this works at least");

    Button yButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_yellow);
    yButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if ( event.equals(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) ) { 
                text1.setText("You pressed the yellow button"); 
                return true; 
            } 

            return false;
        }


    });



    } 



}
```

Comment: See the post from Pentium10 about how to debug an Android app
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222608/android-error-the-application-has-stopped-unexpectedly-please-try-again/3223115#3223115

Comment: you'd take a look at DDMS and the logcat to check the problems http://goo.gl/i9by

Comment: Why an `OnTouchListener` instead of an `OnClickListener` for a button?

Answer (score 1):

1 problem is that `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is of type `int` so for your test to be correct, you should have

```
if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all an `OnTouchListener` is not really the appropriate listener for a `Button` except you are doing very special things. You should implement an `OnClickListener` for your `Button`.

And also consider what ccheneson posted. You are not comparing it correctly.